# is the main purpose of using Schmidt decompositon to visualize entanglement?

Tags: schmidt-decomposition

Is it correct to say that an entanglement state is entangled in any basis, but this fact may not be evident (like in the state $ \frac{1}{ 2} | 00 \rangle + \frac{1}{ 2}| 01 \rangle + \frac{1}{ 2}| 10 \rangle -\frac{1}{ 2}| 11 \rangle$), so performing a Schmidt decomposition may help to visualize the entanglement ( $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}} | 0+ \rangle + \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2}}| 1- \rangle $)?

Is the main purpose of Schmidt decomposition to visualize entanglement or are there other uses for it?

Comment: No, I would say its primary use is as a proof tool. If you want to prove something about pure states it is often quite handy.